# How to paginate a sorted list in Typo3 10?

Tags: fluid, typo3-10.x

I created an extension on Typo3 which is used to list the businesses. This extension is composed of a list page and a widget which is used to make a search on the home page and which sends back to the list page the results.

Everything is functional but I just have a problem with the pagination. When I search for a business from the home page, the paginate works fine when you are redirected to the list page. But when I sort by category directly on the list page, the first page of the pagination is functional but when I click on page 2, all the businesses appear.

So I wanted to try by adding as argument addQueryStringMethod="POST" but this is not supported since version 10 of Typo3.

Here is my pagination:

```html
<f:widget.paginate objects="{commerces}" as="paginatedCommerces"
    configuration="{itemsPerPage: 3, insertAbove: 0, insertBelow: 1, maximumNumberOfLinks: 10}">
        <f:for each="{paginatedCommerces}" as="commerce" iteration="iterator">
          <f:render partial="Commerce/Pagination.html" arguments="{commerce: commerce}" />
        </f:for>
</f:widget.paginate>
```

I've seen similar problems on Google but never any answers so if anyone has any ideas, I'm interested!